# Xcode 6.1.11 - Archive apps don't have icon

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I bult an app, I have icons working on a device, but when I archive my app and look under Organizer -> Archives My app does not have an icon, this is what shows:

[image]

What Do I have to do to get an icon for my apps in Archives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Icon file entry in your app's Info.plist file refers to an existing file in your project. You might need to copy the file into the root of your project to make sure that it will be found.

[image: Icon file]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here is the required App Icons for iPhone/iPad/Universal App [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Good Luck

Comment: you must add all required App icons images to your project (such as 120x120 for iOS 7). See the attached screenshot